# Django query - "case when" with aggregation function

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following django model (mapped to table 'A'):

```
class A(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64, null=False)
    value = models.IntegerField()
    ...
```

I want to perform the following simple query on top:

```
select avg(case 
        when (value > 0 and value <= 50) then 0 
        when (value > 50 and value < 70) then 50 
        else 100 end) 
from A
where ...
```

I'm trying to avoid raw SQL - How can this be implemented with django (in the above example I'm using avg, but the same question is also relevant for max, min, sum etc.)?

I tried using extra and aggregate:

```
extra(select={'avg_field': case_when_query})
```

and

```
aggregate(Avg('avg_field')),
```

but the aggregate function only works with model fields so the extra field cannot be used here.
How can this be done with django?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What can be done that will still allow us to use django queryset is something like this:

```
qs = A.objects.extra(select={"avg_field": 
                     "avg(case when...)"}).filter(...).values("avg_field")
```

To use the result:

```
qs[0]["avg_field"]
```

And this would allow the needed functionality.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know there is (unfortunately) no way to do what you described without resorting to raw SQL.

That said there *is* a way to calculate the average the way you describe if you are willing to denormalize your data a bit. For instance you can add a new column called `average_field` that is automatically set to the appropriate value on `save()`. You can either override `save()` or tap a signal to do this automatically. For e.g.

```
class A(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64, null=False)
    value = models.IntegerField()
    average_field = models.IntegerField(default = 0)

    def _get_average_field(self):
        # Trying to match the case statement's syntax.
        # You can also do 0 < self.value <= 50
        if self.value > 0 and self.value <= 50:
            return 0
        elif self.value > 50 and self.value < 70:
            return 50
        else:
            return 100

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.value:
            self.average_field = self._get_average_field()
        super(A, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Once you do this your querying becomes very easy.

```
A.objects.filter(...).aggregate(avg = Avg('average_field'))
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I can't store these values in the database table since the "case when" values might vary based on the computation I want to perform.

Comment: @Li: understood. I can see why this wouldn't work in that case.

Comment: Thanks again for the help. Eventually using extra + values got me the result I wanted.

Answer (score 3):

Django 1.8 will support CASE WHEN expressions out of the box, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/conditional-expressions/